# Javascript : Why does "10-2" returns "-8" instead of "8"

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, numbers

Here is my code :

```js
function jeu(x, y) {
  let v1 = x,
    v2 = x;
  x > y ? v1 = y : v2 = y;
  alert(v2 - v1);
}

jeu(2, 10);
```

There is 2 parameters : `x` and `y`.

The two first line are putting to `v1` the smallest value and to `v2` the biggest as you can understand. But when I use some numbers like `jeu(2,10)`, the code returns a negative number whereas I am doing "Biggest - Smallest".

Does anybody know why it does that ? (sorry for my bad english)(I can't put this like code, idk why.

Comment: Ignoring the actual code you've listed, you can use `Math.abs(...)` to get the absolute (positive) value of a given number, so `Math.abs(x - y)` will be positive regardless of whether `x` is greater than `y`.

Comment: you can also use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to assign the smaller and bigger numbers. Or just use `if (x > y)`. Your way of doing it is overly confusing.

Comment: When I run your code I get `8` not `-8`.

Comment: @Cully I understand what you mean, but if I do "jeu(2,4)", it returns "2" what is not a negative number.

Comment: @Cully Your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar , oh thanks I forgot I could use these.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating two variables `v1` and `v2` which are hard to understand, name them `min` and `max`. Assign both of them with conditional logic.

```js
function jeu(x, y) {
  const
    max = x > y ? x : y,
    min = x < y ? x : y;
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ min, max }));
  return max - min;
}

console.log(jeu(2, 10) === jeu(10, 2));
```

May be overkill, but you could use `Math.min` and `Math.max` as well:

```js
function jeu(x, y) {
  const
    max = Math.max(x, y)
    min = Math.min(x, y);
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ min, max }));
  return max - min;
}

console.log(jeu(2, 10) === jeu(10, 2));
```

The simpler version is calling `Math.abs`:

```js
function jeu(x, y) {
  return Math.abs(x - y);
}

console.log(jeu(2, 10) === jeu(10, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `"10"` and `"2"` are treated as strings, not as numbers.

If you want to perform numeric subtraction, you should convert the strings to numbers using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` like this:

```js
function jeu(x, y) {
  let v1 = parseInt(x, 10); // Convert x to an integer
  let v2 = parseInt(x, 10); // Convert x to an integer
  x > y ? v1 = parseInt(y, 10) : v2 = parseInt(y, 10);
  alert(v2 - v1);
}

jeu(2, 10);
```